# Out of Bounds Iterator for List

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it valid or undefined to do the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<int> a = { 10 };

    auto it = std::prev(a.begin()); // potential out of bounds here

    std::list<int> b;

    b.splice(b.begin(), a);

    a.push_back(12);

    std::cout << *std::next(it);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically want to get an iterator that points to an object such that when I remove an element from the list I can reference where in the list it was removed, such that I can insert it back to where it's suppose to be. The problem arises when I remove the first element of the list as there is no element there. I've read some implementation details and it seems for the most part that it is valid so long as the iterator is not dereferenced.

http://ideone.com/26Xfba

Seems to work in GCC/CLang, but I get debug warnings in VC++.

EDIT:

Just to clarify what I am aiming at, I -need- an implementation of the splice function such that I can splice out sectors of a list in and out from one another...

```
// Note not valid code... really just a concept of what I need...
std::list<int> a = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
std::list<int> b = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };

auto b1 = std::advance(a.begin(), 1);
auto e1 = std::advance(a.end(),  -2);

auto b2 = b.begin();
auto e2 = b.end();

a.splice(b1, e1, b, b2, e2);

// a = { 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 40 }
// b = { 20, 30 }

b.splice(b1, e1, a, b2, e2);

// a = { 10, 20, 30, 40 }
// b = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
```

Comment: It's UB, but if I understood correctly what you mean, why don't you reverse how your code works and reference the *next* object? You can get back to the previous one just as easily, and going one after the last element is allowed (you get `end()`). http://ideone.com/wfrEkj

Comment: Good suggestion but I need it to work both ways.

Comment: What do you mean with "both ways"?

Comment: Such that you can point to the start of where the element was and where the end was. You have me thinking now, wouldn't `std::prev(a.begin()) == a.rend()` ?

Comment: `list.erase()` returns an iterator pointing to essentially where it was removed from, `list.insert()` puts an item at that iterator. No need to reimplement this iterator saving mechanism.

Comment: I'm not erasing it though, I'm "splicing" it into another list. Maybe I should have clarified, I'm splice'ing ~many~ elements from list to list, eg swapping out sections of a list. What I really need is an implementation of splice such that `splice(iterator first, iterator second, list& x, iterator first, iterator second)` ...

Comment: The splice function has `splice(iterator position, list& x, iterator first, iterator second)`, does that not do what you want?

Comment: It only specifies where the contents of one list goes into another and then moves it there. I want to specify the start and end of a range such that if you think of a chain, you would be swapping where a section of chain for another one. I updated the first post with an example.

Comment: I think that probably you have to manually keep the first element as a "sentinel", without storing any data in it.

Comment: I think I may have figured it, I was approaching it from the wrong angle, thanks for the comments they helped :). I could do what you said Matteo as I don't need to know the position at the front where to insert it so long as I keep track of the start of both sectors.